# How do I split a string by each character but ignore not when the character is special

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have uniqueId labels that I'm trying to have read out properly by voice over which are a mix of numbers, letters and special characters.

I want to split a string by each character except when it is a special character.

For example

If I have

`const string =  'ABC9!3J;R7.T'`

Now obviously `string.split('')` will equal `['A', 'B', 'C', '9', '!', '3', 'J', ';', 'R', '7', '.', 'T']` which is not what I want.

So what regex do I need to use in to get the split function to ignore special characters so I will have this expected.

`expected = ['A', 'B', 'C', '9!', '3', 'J;', 'R', '7.', 'T']`

Regex is not my forte so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried using a few regex's using Phind and looking for something similar on stack overflow but it seems as if people usually want to do the opposite of what I want.

Comment: What is your definition of "not special"? Alphanumeric?

Answer (score 0):

If you know exactly which are those characters you want to treat as *special*, list them in a greedy list `[]?`

```bash
/.[!;.]?/gm
```

[Regex101.com demo](https://regex101.com/r/lF7fsc/2)

Comment: Yeah I think I've got it down to 5 or so. Thanks Roko, I'll test it and let you know!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex match to create a new array with the correct elements you want instead of using `split`.

```js
const regex = /.[^a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9]/gm;
const str = 'ABC9!3J;R7.T';
const strArray = str.match(regex);

console.log(strArray);
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ij5neo/1)

Answer (score 0):

Define regex to check for the special characters then iterate over the string and build an array of substrings, concatenating special characters with the last element of the array if the current character is a special character.

JS(Demo only)

```js
const string = 'ABC9!3J;R7.T';
const specialCharsRegex = /[!@#$%&*()\-_+=[\]{}:';"<>?/\\|~^.]/g;
let result = [];
for (let i =  0; i < string.length; i++) {
    let char = string[i];
    if (specialCharsRegex.test(char)) {
        result[result.length -  1] += char;
    } else {
        result.push(char);
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

Sample on React

```
import React from 'react';

const SpecialCharactersProcessor = () => {
  const string = 'ABC9!3J;R7.T';
  const specialCharsRegex = /[!@#$%&*()\-_+=[\]{}:';"<>?/\\|~^.]/g;

  const processString = () => {
    let result = [];
    for (let i =  0; i < string.length; i++) {
      let char = string[i];
      if (specialCharsRegex.test(char)) {
        result[result.length -  1] += char;
      } else {
        result.push(char);
      }
    }
    return result;
  };

  // Call the function and store the result in the state
  const [processedResult, setProcessedResult] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setProcessedResult(processString());
  }, []); // Empty dependency array means this effect runs once on mount

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Render the processed result */}
      {processedResult.map((item, index) => (
        <p key={index}>{item}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SpecialCharactersProcessor;
```